# Displaying values and information

Tags: python, json, bots, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role( 703596629873131590, 703596629894365209, 703596629894365210, 703596629894365211, 703596629923725334, 703596629911142433 )
async def info_pred(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    with open('pred.json', 'r') as f:
        moders = json.load(f)

    if member == ctx.author or member == None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = '**PRED INFO**',description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, **на данный момент у Вас** `{moders[str(ctx.author.id)]["Pred"]}` **предупреждений**' ,color = random.choice(colors))
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)

    else:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = '**PRED INFO**',description = f'**У модератора** {member.mention} `{moders[str(member.id)]["Pred"]}` **предупреждений**' ,color = random.choice(colors))
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

**json**

```
{"388421980472475648": {"Pred": 4}, "507619532391579658": {"Pred": 0}, "287605474692431873": {"Pred": 1}, "350257225731801090": {"Pred": 1}, "464411914261233664": {"Pred": 1}}
```

Good day. I don’t break how to make it so that with the command !info_prev the entire list of members and their arg will be displayed

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve and what problems you're having, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You may loop through the list of members `ctx.guild.members` and get their IDs

```
@commands.command()
async def info_prev(ctx):
    for members in ctx.guild.members:
        await ctx.send(moders[str(members.id)]["Pred"])
```